How to make \w token act non-greedy in this RegEx?
I have a text string which contains a repeating pattern, each repetion separated by the next by the . (dot) character. The pattern may end in a _123 (underscore followed by a sequence of digits), and I want to catch those digits in a dedicated capturing group.
The RegEx (ECMAScript) I have built mostly works:
https://regex101.com/r/iEzalU/1
/(label(:|\+))?(\w+)(?:_(\d+))?/gi

However, the (\w+) part acts greedy, and overtakes the (?:_(\d+))? part.

Adding a ? to make \w+ non-greedy (\w+?) works, but now I have a capturing token for each character matched by \w

How can I make this regex such that \w+ acts greedy but still does not overtake the _(\d+) part?
Otherwise, is it possible to capture all tokens matched by the non-greedy \w+?, as a single match? (some capturing/non-capturing groups magic?)

Does (label(:|\+))?([^\W_]+|_(\d+))+ do what you need?

If the repetion doesn't end with underscore and some numbers, do you want to capture it?

If you have . as separator then use (label[:+])?(\w+?)(?:_(\d+))?(?=\.|$)

If you have only a-z in the first part (label[:+])?([a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*)(?:_(\d+))?(?=\.|$) https://regex101.com/r/dPfrIs/1

Clarifying for future reference, though, Wiktor's answer was what i was looking for. Yes, I do want to capture the sequence of it doesn't end with digits, i just wanted a separate capturing group for those. The sequence can contain _\d+ in between, I'm only interested in the ending part. And no, i can't assume [a-z] only instead of \w (particularly, I know for sure that I will have underscores and digits)

When creating regular expressions, it is a good idea to think about your expected match boundaries.
You know you need to match substrings in a longer string, so $ and \z can be excluded at once. Digits, letters, underscores are all word characters matched with \w, so you want to match all up to a character other than a word character (or, potentially, till the end of string).
I suggest using
(label[:+])?(\w+?)(?:_(\d+))?\b

See the regex demo
Details:

(label[:+])? - an optional Group 1: label and then a : or +
(\w+?) - Group 2: one or more word chars as few as possible
(?:_(\d+))?  - an optional sequence of: _ and then one or more digits captured into Group 3
\b - the next char can only be a non-word char or end of string should follow.


Wow, that \b caught me completely off-guard. Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed!
